# Захват звука на Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, аудио, python-3.5

Всем привет.
Небольшое уточнение: как транслировать звук с динамика на микрофон без воспроизведения средствами Python 3?

У меня есть ссылка на аудио-файл, которую я передаю в форму на сайт [спичпад](http://speechpad.ru).
Мне нужно выполнить транскрибацию этого аудио-файла. Этот сайт проигрывает файл на колонках и распознает в нем слова. Мне нужно чтобы звук транслировался в микрофон без воспроизведения в динамиках. Как это реализовать? Система Mac OS X 10.7 Mavericks.

Много гуглил по этому вопросу и ничего дельного не нашел.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Есть великолепная библиотека PyAudio, с её помощью можно конвертировать аудио дорожку в лист
Это пример записи голоса с микрофона, конвертирование в аудиодорожку, Вы можете использовать лист frames, который по сути и будет расложенным аудио

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import struct

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 1024
RECORD_SECONDS = 6
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "file.wav"

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# start Recording
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE, input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
print("recording...")
frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)
print("finished recording")

# stop Recording
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()

waveFile = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
waveFile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
waveFile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
waveFile.setframerate(RATE)
waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
waveFile.close()
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ :) я позже гляну :) решил попробовать написать свою НН для распознавания слов)